# Parse identifiers that don't end with certain characters in attoparsec

Tags: haskell, regex-lookarounds, attoparsec

I am stuck writing an attoparsec parser to parse what the [Uniform Code for Units of Measure](http://unitsofmeasure.org/ucum.html#section-Character-Set-and-Lexical-Rules) calls a `<ATOM-SYMBOL>`. It's defined to be the longest sequence of characters in a certain class (that class includes all the digits 0-9) which doesn't end with a digit.

So given the input `foo27` I want to consume and return `foo`, for `237bar26` I want to consume and return `237bar`, for `19` I want to fail without consuming anything.

I can't figure out how to build this out of `takeWhile1` or `takeTill` or `scan` but I am probably missing something obvious.

Update:
My best attempt so far was that I managed to exclude sequences that are entirely digits

```
atomSymbol :: Parser Text
atomSymbol = do
               r <- core
               if (P.all (inClass "0-9") . T.unpack $ r)
                 then fail "Expected an atom symbol but all characters were digits."
                 else return r
  where
    core = A.takeWhile1 $ inClass "!#-'*,0-<>-Z\\^-z|~"
```

I tried changing that to test if the last character was a digit instead of if they all were, but it doesn't seem to backtrack one character at a time.

Update 2:

The whole file is at https://github.com/dmcclean/dimensional-attoparsec/blob/master/src/Numeric/Units/Dimensional/Parsing/Attoparsec.hs. This only builds against the `prefixes` branch from https://github.com/dmcclean/dimensional.

Comment: Here's a combinator that might help you: `notFollowedBy p = p >> fail "not followed by"`

Comment: Please make your question self-contained and add your import statements. Here, one is left wondering (even though one might guess) what qualified imports `A`, `P`, and `T` correspond to.

Comment: Could you take the whole token, reverse it, drop digits, reverse back and check if anything has left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reformulate the problem and treat spans of digits (`0-9`) and spans of non-digit characters (`!#-'*,:-<>-Z\\^-z|~`) separately. The syntactic element of interest can then be described as

- an optional digit span, followed by
- a non-digit span, followed by
- zero or more {digit span followed by a non-digit span}.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Control.Applicative ((<|>), many)
import Data.Char (isDigit)

import Data.Attoparsec.Combinator (option)
import Data.Attoparsec.Text (Parser)
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Text as A
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

atomSymbol :: Parser Text
atomSymbol = f <$> (option "" digitSpan)
               <*> (nonDigitSpan <|> fail errorMsg)
               <*> many (g <$> digitSpan <*> nonDigitSpan)
  where
    nonDigitSpan = A.takeWhile1 $ A.inClass "!#-'*,:-<>-Z\\^-z|~"
    digitSpan    = A.takeWhile1 isDigit
    f x y xss    = T.concat $ x : y : concat xss
    g x y        = [x,y]
    errorMsg     = "Expected an atom symbol but all characters (if any) were digits."
```

## Tests

> [...] given the input `foo27` I want to consume and return foo, for `237bar26` I want to consume and return `237bar`, for `19` I want to fail without consuming anything.

```
λ> A.parseOnly atomSymbol "foo26"
Right "foo"

λ> A.parseOnly atomSymbol "237bar26"
Right "237bar"

λ> A.parseOnly atomSymbol "19"
Left "Failed reading: Expected an atom symbol but all characters (if any) were digits."
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, thanks much. I'm sorry for the delay in giving feedback on it, I was absolutely swamped at the office.

Comment: @DougMcClean No problem.